# Laravel Nested Query Multiple Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am running a query where I have to Filter Products based on Company or Brand or a combination of Both.

Below is my query which I am using.

```php
$products = ProductInventoryMapping::with([
    'distributor',
    'product.unit',
    'product.subbrand',
    'product.brand' => function ($query) use ($search_brand) {
        if(strlen($search_brand) > 0) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search_brand.'%');
        }
    },
    'product.brandcompany' => function ($query) use ($search_company) {
        if(strlen($search_company) > 0) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search_company.'%');
        }
    }
])->where('user_id', $id)->get()
```

But I am facing an issue. My brand or company relation object is coming null irrespective it matches or not. Thus while printng, I am not able to access the data.

```
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object", exception: "ErrorException
```

```
foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
    $r = $value->product->brand->name
    $r2 = $value->product->brandcompany->name
}
```

Comment: could you post the result of dd($products) in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain the relationship is present? If some products do not have brand or brandcompany, then you have 2 options

- Use `has` or `whereHas` to make sure you're only getting objects that have the relationships.
- Check if the relationship is not null before trying to access its values